# How do I set the directory for Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am trying to run this code in Code::Blocks to test my project:

```
FILE *tFile = fopen("findloc.txt", "w");
```

However, it puts the file in Users/Pon3 instead of Users/Pon3/Projects/MyProject which is where I want it to go. How can I fix this in Code::Blocks (Mac OS X Mountain Lion)?

Comment: Give it an absolute path (or a relative path to that directory)?

Comment: @chris How? I set the execution working directory.

Comment: If it's already in `Users/Pon3`, you can just give it `"Projects/MyProject/findloc.txt"` to navigate deeper within that directory.

Comment: @chris I don't think I understand. Give what `"Projects/MyProject/findloc.txt"`

Comment: The `fopen` call. The alternative is passing `"Users/Pon3/Projects/MyProject/findloc.txt"`.

Comment: @chris I'm having problems with other code because of it too. That just fixes the fopen() code.

Answer (score 2):

`"Users/pon3/Projects/MyProject/findloc.txt"` would put your text file more specifically were you want.

If you simply write  `FILE *tFile = fopen("findloc.txt", "w");`, your text file is going to be were code::block put his files.

Comment: I have more problems than just with fopen(). That fix won't work fully.

Comment: Can you describe what are you other problems?

Comment: For instance, my program can't find specific Lua files located in Projects/MyProject